# Is loose coupling possible for a web app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, oop

I understand that content, presentation, and behavior are supposed to be separated by using HTML, CSS, and JS to implement them independently.  Is there a best practice for binding these elements concretely while maintaining loose coupling in a dynamic web app?  Is it even possible?  Optimally without depending on jQuery?

To clarify what I'm talking about: HTML has no mechanism for the definition of new tags, so when your JavaScript model needs to generate content, the tags and structure for its presentation are necessarily defined in JS or somehow made accessible to it, tightly coupling behavior to content.

Before someone calls over-OOP, the reason I want to keep tags and CSS classes out of JS is that I don't even want to commit to HTML as a front end.  There are at least five different representations of my underlying model that I'll eventually want, and tightly coupling the model to HTML rules out at least two of them.

Is there some way to late bind the model to the target representation without sacrificing dynamics or loose coupling?  Like an XML document corresponding model elements to template HTML snippets?

UPDATE

Though it seems backward to provide concrete details of a question about factoring and OO best practice, I want to provide a much fresher example of the entanglement of form & function inherent to HTML.  The entanglement of content & behavior between HTML and JS is the problem, though, not the example, and I want an answer that doesn't break when I change the details.  It's from a very different project than the one I was working when I first asked this question, but the gist is the same:

- I have some HTML for a UI widget.  It is a view that represents a model object - a selection of palettes - to the user.  Palettes themselves are part of the app's task, so they're not view, they're model.
- I want to use this widget in at least 2 different dialogs (and any I might want in the future).  In one, I need a changed selection to cause immediate action, the recoloring of a set of images in canvas elements that are part of the same dialog.  In another, I just need to have two different sets to select from - one selection in each set.
- I do not want to copy and paste this widget's HTML form or JS behavior because I want maintenance and revision to propagate from one base thing to all of its instances.  Thus, only one instance of the widget, whatever its form may be, may exist in my source.
- I do not want to have my JS rendering HTML tags directly because doing so will forfeit my IDE's error checking and content assistance on the HTML.  Further, if there are problems with the HTML output, their source in my JS will be less clear because the process of generating the HTML doesn't look like HTML or necessarily reflect its structure.  Finally, I want to test the effects of changes to the widget's CSS and HTML independently of my JS.
- I do not want to involve additional dependencies e.g. separate templating & parameterization languages in my source because changes to various standards or evolving needs may break their compatibility, or they may themselves become unmaintained, in the future, leaving me with a massive quantity of useless source.  Depending on jQuery is okay because it does more for normalizing between browsers (not to mention for convenience) than it is likely to ever break given its ubiquity, but other libraries will be regarded with extreme suspicion.
- I want to specify the details of altering and retrieving the widget's state (what colors compose the palettes, how the user chooses among them) in JS that references only the widget and its component parts, since it's going to be a part of multiple dialogs that use its information in different ways.
- Simultaneously, other JS code (the dialog's behavior) needs to be able to observe and initialize the widget's state - but without including any specific references to the widget's internal structure, which may some day change to accommodate new features, fix bugs, etc.

For simply making multiple copies of the widget's HTML, I can settle on calling `jquery.clone` on a template node that exists in an HTML file, and inserting the contents where I need them, from the function that sets up the dialog.  HTML makes things difficult when any of the cloned elements have `id` or `name` attributes, but careful handling during cloning can make unique identifiers, point their corresponding `label` elements and `href` attributes at the new identifiers, and keep the old ones accessible in data attributes.  So all is well and good for structure & content, and obviously the CSS presentation propagates to the clone just fine.

The rub comes when I try to implement the widget's interface with its dialog's controller.  What is the most future-proof way to expose the widget's state's abstraction?  I.e. I don't want to use `widgetJquery.find('input:checked').val()` to get the selected color from code that doesn't absolutely have to commit to a selection being based on a checked input element whose value attribute is a set of serialized colors.

I hope that makes it more clear what I'm looking for without muddling the question with details.

Comment: Just curious: what non-HTML front end would you still use JS for? Regarding your comment about not depending on jQuery, I _like_ jQuery, but note that it is written in JS so it can't do anything you couldn't manually code in JS yourself...

Comment: @nnnnnn IDE-integrated documentation and interchange formats are the non-HTML representations I want.  They're for exposing the same model to very different sets of users.

Comment: can you explain exactly in your question what you are doing? there may be other methods that can be worked out rather than closing in on what you really want. let's be open.

Answer (score 1):

You can always have different XSLTs parse an XML.
But, it seems you try to abstract tooo much.
use the MVC, use different views to parse.

The methodology you write about is common in old systems, I worked with more than 10 years ago, there is probably a good reason evolution killed it.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about which aspect of my concern you think is impractical?  Which tight coupling is not worth avoiding?  I'm by no means an OO guru, just trying to implement my idea in concrete steps without kicking myself later.

Answer (score 1):

Loose coupling is best achieved archtecturally using design patterns.  A great example of how to achieve loose coupling is found in the **[Mediator Pattern](http://arguments.callee.info/2009/05/18/javascript-design-patterns--mediator/)**.  However, there are several patterns to use.

I suggest reading Addy Osmani's **['Essential JavaScript design Patterns'](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjavascript)** for comprehensive coverage of a range of patterns.

Enjoy!